# .NET how to measure how many bytes allocated in a request?

Tags: .net, performance, profiling, clr, memory-management

I need to trace objects that are allocated in a request.
Is there any tool or command that can help me know how many bytes are allocated and when?

Comment: Can you define 'request'. Are you talking about a web request in the context of ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, please clarify. As far as general memory allocation goes, there are plenty of memory profiling tools out there that will tell you how large objects are (e.g. RedGate's memory profiler), but if you're just looking at something like a HTTP request, that's much more trivial.

Comment: Yep- i mean to httprequest. i want to trace where i allocate objects in request scope.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Ants Memory Profile](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)r can help you so much here, however it is not free, but they have a trial version "for 14 days or so", give it a shot.

Comment: I installed ants and dottrace, however - i didnt find a function like this. i might missed it , or its not exists

Comment: I doesn't expose a function to you, when you run your application in the debugger it will sample your memory usage after you stop the debugging and give you a full report on where the memory consumes more which function call or line and of course how much memory spent in each with the time...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLRProfiler sample to see this. Depending on your platform, there is a version for .NET 2 and one for .NET 4. And it is free!

It does pretty graphs/maps to show you where  memory was allocated.

Comment: I tried , but i am getting a message "waiting to clr", and the message doesn't desapear. i google for a solution , but i dosnt success to solve this problem for me , so i gave up, but it seems that this is a good tool.